# How can i change the position of product title and price?

Tags: css, css-transitions

How can i change my product title and price from left to right on single product page woocommerce. right now my title and price is on left

Comment: add your code with `snippet`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe
1 for title add css `text-align: right;`
2 for parent add `display:flex; justify-content: end;`
But will be better if you add a code here.